# Java CPLEX Concert UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-16.04, cplex

I am trying to use cplex in java using eclipse IDE on Ubuntu 16.4

and I am getting an exception "UnsatisfiedLinkError" as follows
Does anybody have an idea how to overcome this exception?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.swig_module_init()'
at ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
at ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.<clinit>(concert_wrapJNI.java:1619)
at ilog.concert.cppimpl.IloEnv.<init>(IloEnv.java:49)
at ilog.opl.IloOplFactory.<init>(IloOplFactory.java:84)
at cplex.Mulprod.main(Mulprod.java:15)
```

I am using the following example provided by [ensta-paris Java version of mulprod.cpp of OPL distrib](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ediam/ro/online/cplex/cplex1271/examples/html/opl_interfaces/java/mulprod/src/mulprod/Mulprod.java.html)

```
import ilog.concert.*; 
import ilog.opl.*;
import ilog.opl.IloCplex;

public class Mulprod {
  static final String DATADIR = ".";

  static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int status = 127;
    try {
        IloOplFactory.setDebugMode(true);
        IloOplFactory oplF = new IloOplFactory();
        IloOplErrorHandler errHandler = oplF.createOplErrorHandler();
        IloOplModelSource modelSource = oplF.createOplModelSource(DATADIR + "/mulprod.mod");
        IloOplSettings settings = oplF.createOplSettings(errHandler);
        IloOplModelDefinition def = oplF.createOplModelDefinition(modelSource, settings);
        IloCplex cplex = oplF.createCplex();
        cplex.setOut(null);
        IloOplModel opl = oplF.createOplModel(def, cplex);
        IloOplDataSource dataSource = oplF.createOplDataSource(DATADIR + "/mulprod.dat");
        opl.addDataSource(dataSource);
        opl.generate();
        if (cplex.solve()) {
            System.out.println("OBJECTI " + opl.getCplex().getObjValue());
            opl.postProcess();
            opl.printSolution(System.out);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No solution!");
        }
        oplF.end();
        status = 0;
    } catch (IloOplException ex) {
        System.err.println("### OPL excepti " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        status = 2;
    } catch (IloException ex) {
        System.err.println("### CONCERT excepti " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        status = 3;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("### UNEXPECTED UNKNOWN ERROR ...");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        status = 4;
    }
    System.exit(status);
}
}
```

my VM arguments in run configuration are

```
-Djava.library.path=[cplexStudioPath]/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux:[cplexStudioPath]/opl/bin/x86-64_linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable so that it includes the OPL directory (which you also specified in `java.library.path`).

Also note that specifying the CPLEX directory in `java.library.path` is not required. I recommend removing it since you don't want libraries to get loaded from this place. You only want the libraries from the OPL directory (the required CPLEX libraries are there as well).

Comment: Thanks, I don't get that exception anymore, but currently, I am getting 
         java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class ilog.concert.cppimpl.IloAddNumVar can not implement ilog.concert.IloColumn, because it is not an interface (ilog.concert.IloColumn is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: That is weird. Do you have multiple installations of CPLEX? Or is maybe one of your jars corrupted? Which jars do you use? The only thing you should need is `oplall.jar`.